# orientation in windows mobile 6.0?

Tags: windows-mobile

i'm having around 13 emulators .i want my app can  adjustable  in all emulators.

how to set orientation for all emulators.is there any way for automatic adjustment.

otherwise how to write the code each emulator for orientaion.can u give some sample example.

in windows phone 7 i simple write margin properties in landscape and portrait.

in 6.0 how to write code for orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the orientation aware control in the [Mobile Client Software Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648751.aspx) (from the patterns and practices group). This allows you to create different layouts for different screen sizes and orientations.

There are also comercial alternatives available.